# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to check connection type?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Can any one help me in knowing the connection type using Worklight API?

I tried using `getNetworkInfo(callback)` but not helpful knowing whether 2G or 3G for both iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight apps are bundled with a version of Cordova.

You can thus use the [Cordova Connection API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection).
With this API you will be able to discern between 2G and 3G connection types and others.

For example, in `your-project\apps\your-app\common\js\main.js`, add the following to `wlCommonInit()`:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

Worklight apps are generated with all required configuration (config.xml, etc...), so no further setup is needed; just adjust the code snippet to your app.

With my iPhone 5s and the specific carrier I am using, I got "Cell generic connection" when using 3G, and "WiFi connection" when using WiFi. So this depends on your carrier setup as well I suspect, but this API does what you asked for.